# That command cannot be used on multiple selections vba named range

Tags: vba, excel

I get the error "That command cannot be used on multiple selections" when I use a named range in VBA.

VBA is being used to derive a formula which is fine but then I want to just paste the values.

```
Set rngCopy = rngCopy.Offset(0, 10).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

rngCopy.Activate

rngCopy.Value = _
    "=IF(RC[-10]="""","""",IF(WEEKDAY(RC[-10])=2,RC[-10]-3,IF(WEEKDAY(RC[-10])<>2,RC[-10]-1)))"

rngCopy.Copy
rngCopy.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, _
Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on? My guess is that you're trying to add a formula to several cells at once. I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I was just trying to copy the formula values.  The formula itself copied fine @ARich just not the copying the values. rngcopy.value = rngcopy.value did work though.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Also if your intention is copy paste the formula as values then you don't need to take that long route. You can simply use `Application.Evaluate`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rngCopy As Range

    Set rngCopy = Range("A1")
    Set rngCopy = rngCopy.Offset(0, 10).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    rngCopy.Value = Application.Evaluate( _
                    "=IF(RC[-10]="""","""",IF(WEEKDAY(RC[-10])=2,RC[-10]-3,IF(WEEKDAY(RC[-10])<>2,RC[-10]-1)))" _
                    )
End Sub
```

Testing with Non Contiguous ranges also works.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rngCopy As Range

    Set rngCopy = Union(Range("A1"), Range("D1"), Range("F1"))

    rngCopy.Activate

    rngCopy.Value = Application.Evaluate( _
                    "=IF(RC[-10]="""","""",IF(WEEKDAY(RC[-10])=2,RC[-10]-3,IF(WEEKDAY(RC[-10])<>2,RC[-10]-1)))" _
                    )
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi I figured it out and did rngcopy.value = rngcopy.value that way it seemed to not get confused about multiple ranges. Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can do that as well but that is not required if you use `Application.Evaluate` ;)

Comment: Ahhh I see. So the application.evaluate code just gives you the value. Will have a play around with that.

Comment: @LouisaThompson: Yup ;)

Comment: For some reason it comes up with #value.  Its a value and not a formula which is a step in the right direction :D Nice function though. This is my code which looks like yours.   rngCopy.Value = Application.Evaluate("=IF(RC[-10]="""","""",IF(WEEKDAY(RC[-10])=2,RC[-10]-3,IF(WEEKDAY(RC[-10])<>2,RC[-10]-1)))")

Comment: It does work when I use the way in my first comment though rngcopy.value = rngcopy.value.  Have just double checked.